# I can't create a video output when a picture is set in VSE. Output file is black for most of the output

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I have a project that plays perfectly in VSE. It has 3 pictures and 2 video clips. All are sized to 1280x720. The whole clip should be about 15 seconds. Audio is from an mp3 file. Project is set to 29 fps.

I chose the mp4 presets, tried rendering, and I get black screen for 10 seconds, 3-5 frames from one video clip, and then it freezes on a frame from the second clip. None of the pictures show up at all.

I've tried changing to a different output, but the file duplicates the result. Are there any suggestions?

using Blender 2.79 (whatever the latest is. downloaded a fresh copy this week)

Comment: Can you share your project so I can try to investigate it? For me it looks like a codecs issue.

Comment: ok, here is the blender file. I think it might be related to my GPU. I've had all sorts of problems since updating to Win10. I'm going to try on a different computer as well.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AltX43w8Syqehl7rckIILrs0LCA7

Comment: Please Pack your assets using File -> External Data -> "Pack all into .blend" and re-upload the .blend file so I can check your media too

Comment: ok, it only put the mp3 file into the blend file. clearly something is wrong with this project. I'm going to start over and try again.

Comment: ok, After trying and failing to recreate this project from scratch and attempting to get Blender to render something proper (and failing) and not being able to add all the files into the .blend file I got fed up and looked for different software.

I was only trying to create a 15 second clip, so I tried NHC VideoPad and in less than 10 minutes I downloaded, installed, created the project I was trying to create and rendered the finished file. 

I am disappointed in blender.

Comment: Still I would like to know what causes the problem - I use VSE a lot and never had such issue.